# Objective C: Adaptive Toolbar On Orientation Change

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uitoolbar

I am having a problem with my toolbar when i change the orientation of my iPad.

i set my nib file into landscape and everything is all right but when i turned it to portrait my toolbar still has the width from the landscape orientation.

how will i make my toolbar adaptive to the orientation change to portrait?

Landscape:
[image]

Portrait:

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` to the toolbar `autoresizingMask` like so:

```
myToolbar.autoresizingMask |= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
```

Or, if your doing this in the Interface Builder, make sure this horizontal bar is selected (others may be selected as well, which is fine):

[image]

More from the [`UIView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) about `autoresizingMask`:

> When a view’s bounds change, that view automatically resizes its
>   subviews according to each subview’s autoresizing mask. You specify
>   the value of this mask by combining the constants described in
>   `UIViewAutoresizing` using the C bitwise OR operator. Combining these
>   constants lets you specify which dimensions of the view should grow or
>   shrink relative to the superview. The default value of this property
>   is `UIViewAutoresizingNone`, which indicates that the view should not be
>   resized at all.
>
> When more than one option along the same axis is set, the default
>   behavior is to distribute the size difference proportionally among the
>   flexible portions. The larger the flexible portion, relative to the
>   other flexible portions, the more it is likely to grow. For example,
>   suppose this property includes the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and
>   `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` constants but does not include
>   the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` constant, thus indicating
>   that the width of the view’s left margin is fixed but that the view’s
>   width and right margin may change. Thus, the view appears anchored to
>   the left side of its superview while both the view width and the gap
>   to the right of the view increase.
>
> If the autoresizing behaviors do not offer the precise layout that you
>   need for your views, you can use a custom container view and override
>   its `layoutSubviews` method to position your subviews more precisely.

Comment: @SeongHo Yea, try just setting it instead of or'ing it like this: `myToolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`

Comment: yeah i already got that but what my real problem is... //look up i edited my post

Comment: @SeongHo Ah, I see.  To fix that you want to adjust the same autoresizingMask properties for the items inside the toolbar.  Make sure the item in the toolbar on the far right has  `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` set and does NOT have `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` set.

Comment: problem fixed, i just simply added a Flexible Space Bar Button Item. thanks anyway, i gained new knowledge from you! :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adjusting the flexible width of your toolbar you could create 2 arrays of toolbar items.  One for portrait and one for landscape.  Fortunately you only have to create the toolbar items once and just add them to the appropriate array(s).

Then during the orientation change you can set the toolbar's items array to the appropriate one.

Good Luck